# Prometheus + Grafana trouble with templating

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

In Grafana make template:

```
Name - Instance
Query - label_values(instance) 
for recive all instance.
And have reqest example:
sum(machine_cpu_cores) by (instance)
```

If sum(machine_cpu_cores) by (instance=~"$Instance") I have error. How do it right? Thanks.

Comment: "Prometheus + Grafana" as a title does not describe your question at all.

Comment: You haven't included your error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that you've misplaced the `=~` operator.

The correct query should look like this:

```
sum(machine_cpu_cores{instance=~"$Instance"}) by (instance)
```